# sql parent child table interview question

Tags: sql, database

I was asked this question at an interview, but I was not familiar with SQL.
I was hoping someone could help me out on the query, so that I can understand the concept.

```
"id"  "name"   "parentid"
------------------------
"1"   "BOSS1"  null
"2"   "A"      "1"
"3"   "B"      "1"
"4"   "C"      "3"
"5"   "BOSS2"  null
"6"   "Q"      "5"
"7"   "T"      "6"
```

1. Given an id, find all the children

so for 1, it should print 1, 2 ,3, 4

I think this is pretty easy, but I can't figure out how to construct the query using union...

thanks

Comment: You're missing the header row, which I assume would be something like id, name, parent_id

Comment: If D.N. is correct there, I don't think you'll need to use a union query for that. Just `SELECT id FROM table WHERE parent_id = 1`

Comment: neither will 1 in that case. I thought you made a typo. How would you expect to get 1,2,3,4 by giving the id 1?

Comment: Right I've just realised (sorry, it is late :P) you want the children, grandchildren, etc

Comment: because for id 4, the parent id is 3, but 3's parent id is 1 - we're grabbing parents and parents' parents.

Comment: Is there a limit to how far up the tree you need to return? Without a limit, I can't think of a way to do it without dynamic sql?

Comment: i saw some post use CTE, no idea what that is, but I remember the answer did not require it...

Comment: assume it always give you an id with parentid = null

Comment: only two possible input are 1 and 5

Comment: so there doesn't want to be a limit? What I'm saying is that with a lot of inner joins you could do it, but you'd need to hard code each 'level' in the tree in.

Comment: I've never actually tried this (and I'm not running SQL or any IDE on this laptop to test) but can you inner join or union a query with itself?

Comment: I don't think it involved hard coding each level...it was something using union like SELECT * FROM table where id = 1 UNION SELECT a.id, a.name, a.parentid from table a , table 2 ......something after this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below union statement will do what you want,

```
select id,name,parentid
from table
where parentid = 1
union
select id,name,parentid
from table
where parentid in (select id
from table
where parentid = 1)
```

Comment: I think this might be it...I guess there is no way to go additional levels without recursion?...

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. With regard to recursion, I like JonAlb's answer.

Comment: Yes, this will only return the direct children of `id` "1" -- the result will be 1, 2, 3 but 4 won''t be.

Answer (score 3):

To go deeper than "child", a CTE works nicely -

```
WITH CTEExample (ID, Name, Parent)
    AS
    (
        SELECT e.ID, e.Name, e.Parent 
        FROM dbo.ExampleTable e WHERE e.ID = 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT e.ID, e.Name, e.Parent 
        FROM dbo.ExampleTable e
        JOIN CTEExample ON e.Parent = CTEExample.ID
    )
   select ID from CTEExample
```

This should return 1,2,3,4.

edit - looks like Jon beat me to this; though I think his 4th line should read `where ID = 1`, rather than `where ParentID = 1`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kevin i've fixed my post as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

for a single level: ie all the direct descendants of 1

```
select id,name,parentid
where parentid = 1
```

will return 1,2,3

to get ALL the children and grandchildren, and beyond if you are using SQL 2005 you can use CTE, which enables recursion:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

```
WITH Person_CTE AS (
SELECT id,name,parentid
FROM TableName
WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ChildTable.id,ChildTable.name,ChildTable.parentid
FROM TableName ChildTable
Inner Join Person_CTE on Person_CTE.ID= ChildTable.parentid
)
SELECT * FROM Person_CTE
```

The SQL will recurse down and join parents onto children until it can find no more children to return

of course you could use a Union, but that would only return the first and second levels (which would suffice for your dataset)